# Custom USB PC-PC Interface

Tags: usb, cables, short-circuit, synchronous

I would like to build a software interface using the [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html) library, for sending triggers for synchronization with the following specifications:

- Latency below 1 ms
- Range: 8-bit [0, 255] + bit [0, 1]
- On the receiving end the bits will be translated to strings (e.g. "S255" or "R128")

I have the following concerns:

1. For two computers with USB 2.0 ports to be connected with a 3m cable, what cable should I use - bridged or unbridged A/A?
2. Should I be concerned about risks for short circuiting or otherwise permanent damage to the hardware?
3. Will a universal USB driver suffice?
4. What USB device class does a direct PC-PC connection classify as?

Note: I have no prior experience of hardware programming.

Comment: Usb was not meant to be used that way. There are usb to usb transfer cables, or usb to Ethernet, or usb to rs232 that you can use, but this would be tons easier over wifi or Ethernet

Comment: What are the synchronization triggers for?  It would be nice to relax the latency requirement.  Do the messages need to be acted upon immediately, or would accurate timestamps be enough?  You could synchronize the computers using a GPS time source or IEEE 1588.

Comment: @Justin The triggers sync the onset of what happens on the screen (computer 1) with the position of a marker that is set during recording of waveforms* (computer 2) using EEG**. This in turn enables us to create a time window***, which is locked to the changes on screen. Say, if the participant has been watching nothing but blinking oranges on the screen and suddenly a banana shows up, we expect a different waveform representing the change. 

* Similar to audio recording.
** We investigate the electrical currents emanating from the human brain through the scalp.
*** For averaging the signal

Comment: @Justin When using timestamps we have to consider that I do not have a separate clock, but two different CPUs at different cycles. Would it be possible to time lock to a GPS source with submillisecond precision?

IEEE 1588 is new to me. It sounds intriguing! Do I need an independent clock/master?

Comment: Is it not possible to do the EEG recording and image display on the same PC?

Comment: The EEG recording is monitored simultaneously and any parallel activity could produce glitches during the acquisition or stimulus presentation. The recording and monitoring of 32-channel waveforms (ADC to USB) at a sample rate of 2000Hz is processor heavy. An additional point is that the responses we record through a keyboard also need to sync, more or less.

Answer (score 3):

1. A "bridged" cable. Unbridged A/A cables should not be made and may harm your computer (2).

3/4. This depends on your cable. The bridged cables usually pretend to be two Ethernet interfaces joined back-to-back. The exact interface will depend on your manufacturer.

(Implied) This will almost certainly not achieve 1ms latency; you are much better off connecting them with a short gigabit Ethernet cable and achieving synchronisation over that.

Comment: @Passerby I have already tried setting up a TCP/IP socket. The problem is that the lag is ~40ms on our network. I guess that the packet size also effects the transmission. The default solution, in my case, used to be parallel port communication (through rs-232), but interfacing with the old drivers is cumbersome on a modern computer. Do you think I should be using a direct PC-PC Ethernet crossover cable instead and reduce the lag through optimizing the software? I only have a single Ethernet port and would like to keep the network connection.

Comment: Maybe I should be using a 2-Port RJ45 Splitter?

Comment: Usb overhead might make that too laggy. If you need a very minimal lag for just this, consider using the built in Ethernet for this, and a pair of usb or pci network cards for the normal networking.

Comment: Use the ethernet port for a direct PC-PC connection. Crossover cable not required unless you're stuck in 10MB land. If your LAN ping is 40ms something is broken; if you need another port buy a PCI or USB ethernet device and connect that to the slow network.